# How can I change the content of a span nested in a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the content of the span class"push-me" which is "+" to a "-" on alternative clicks of the "container-heading" class.

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#nrOne').toggleClass('black');
  $("#our").toggleClass('blue');
})
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
.blue {
  color: #66cccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-heading">
  
  <h4 id="our">Our Services
    <span class="push-me"> + </span>
  </h4>
  
  <p>Aliquam mauris metus, viverra ac faucibus vitae, pellentesque vitae.</p>
  
</div>

<button id="btn1">Button </button>
<!--container heading end-->
```

So far, the code works, I just need to add this last functionality. Any help or tips are highly appreciated:) Thank you in advance & have a nice day StackOverflow!

Comment: sorry the question is bit unclear for me, what did you mean by " alternative clicks" there ?

Comment: @IreshaRubasinghe he means alternate - First click shows a `-`, second a `+`, third a `-` again and so on

Comment: oh thanks, got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not suggest you to directly access `span` using `class`, as many elements can have same class. You should use button `id` and then inside it you should use `class` to search element.

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#nrOne').toggleClass('black');
  $("#our").toggleClass('blue');
  var text = $("#our > .push-me").text().trim() === "+"?"-": "+";
  $("#our > .push-me").text(text);
})
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
.blue {
  color: #66cccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-heading">
  
  <h4 id="our">Our Services
    <span class="push-me"> + </span>
  </h4>
  
  <p>Aliquam mauris metus, viverra ac faucibus vitae, pellentesque vitae.</p>
  
</div>

<button id="btn1">Button </button>
<!--container heading end-->
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make it neater by using CSS and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after). This links the content directly to the current state of the button, rather than just toggling the content and hoping it stays in sync, e.g. if some other code set the CSS class but did not update the content.

```
#our > span.push-me::after {
  content:' + ';
}

#our.blue > span.push-me::after {
  content:' - ';
}
```

Then no other changes are required, other than removing the initial `+` from the `<span>` HTML.

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#nrOne').toggleClass('black');
  $("#our").toggleClass('blue');
})
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
.blue {
  color: #66cccc;
}

#our > span.push-me::after {
  content:' + ';
}

#our.blue > span.push-me::after {
  content:' - ';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-heading">
  
  <h4 id="our">Our Services
    <span class="push-me"></span>
  </h4>
  
  <p>Aliquam mauris metus, viverra ac faucibus vitae, pellentesque vitae.</p>
  
</div>

<button id="btn1">Button </button>
<!--container heading end-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set it with jquery

```
$(".push-me").text(" - ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this script also : -->

```
$('.container-heading').click(function() 
{
    if ($(".push-me").text() == "-")
    {
          $('.push-me').text('+');
    }
    else
    {
          $('.push-me').text('-');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click handler to .push-me.

```js
$('.push-me').on('click', function() {
 var txt = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(txt.trim()  == '+' ? ' - ' : ' + ');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-heading">
    <h4 id="our">Our Services<span class="push-me"> + </span></h4>
    <p>Aliquam mauris metus, viverra ac faucibus vitae, pellentesque vitae.</p>
</div> <!--container heading end-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, something like this:

```
$('.container-heading').click(function() {
  var pushme = $(this).find('.push-me');
  var txt = $(pushme).text();
  $(pushme).text( txt === ' + ' ? ' - ' : ' + ');        
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Lw4Lv5g3/